# Other way to disconnect user/client in mySql 5.6?

Tags: mysql-5.6

Hello everyone is there another way of disconnecting user/client aside from:

```
kill id
```

I have a close button which when i click the button it will close the connection on the selected user... but the problem in my side is that connection ID is changed every process... i can't determine which connection ID should be killed.

this syntax also didn't work using laravel db query..

```
DB::select( " SELECT CONCAT('KILL ',  $userCon, ';') FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user = $id;");
```

Hope anyone could help me... Thanks in advance.

Note: I used Laravel in my Web.

Comment: databases don't have close buttons. What problem are you having / trying to solve?

Comment: Hello sir, I created a button <close connection> which when i click that button it will close the user connection in my database.. here is the full problem i asked in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088196/how-to-kickdisconnect-specific-user-client-in-mysql-using-laravel-query?noredirect=1#comment91127517_52088196

Comment: my problem by the way is that, how to close user's connection? because every time the user visit another page there's new connection so it's not static.

Comment: new database connection for new pages are a good thing in mysql. New connections are quick. Don't try to share them as shared pool require a lot of state being maintained on the server side.

Comment: @danblack but how I can kick(disconnect) user from accessing the web? like if I click button <Close Button> the user will be disconnected from database/web.

Comment: Close buttons don't mean anything at a database layer. You want to disconnect from application code? maybe the `$userCon`  has a disconnect method. You should never need `KILL` in an application code. Closing browers in the middle of a request? The server code can't see it has gone away. But really I think you should just ignore any phantom connections.

Comment: @danblack the client want to disconnect user if he want.... the $userCon is the connection id in the "Show full processlist"...

Comment: @danblack hey man, I just confirmed yesterday on what's the purpose of disconnecting the user in database and the client said that if the user will login in multiple station the system admin has the power to disconnect the 2nd login of the same user for their purchase license is maximum of 10 only. the second purpose of this one is that to disconnect user when his hang... and the system admin can kill the process of that user and he will be kick/disconnect from the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing limits: [ALTER USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) and set `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS`.

If you where using MariaDB you'd have [KILL USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-manipulation-kill-connection-query/)

Otherwise, for MySQL and non-MariaDB, for killing off connections try the following SQL:

```
select @kill := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL ',  id, ';')) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user = $id;;
PREPARE stmt FROM @kill;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: but i'm using mysql sir...  do you have any idea?  i already used $conn =  DB::select("KILL $userCon"); but doesn't work. i got this error General error: 1094 Unknown thread id: 40 (SQL: KILL 40)",

Comment: I noticed something.... when i query Show full processlist in mysql the id that i stored in my user table is not there? is it impossible to store process id using Laravel Logincontroller?